# Google Compute Engine Persistent Disk pricing API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Is there any API services to get the details of Persistent Disk pricing for all the regions?.

Pricing details for the Standard machine types can get it from cloudbilling API (ref: https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api).

Is there any similar APIs for Persistent Disk pricing? (ref: https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the SKU browser:
https://cloud.google.com/skus/?currency=USD&filter=D973-5D65-BAB2

This SKU (`D973-5D65-BAB2`) covers Standard PD for asia-east1, europe-west1, us-central1, us-east1, us-west1. I assume it's affiliated with Compute Engine (`services/6F81-5844-456A`).

I tried using API Explorer ([link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/billing/cloudbilling/v1/cloudbilling.services.skus.list?parent=services%252F6F81-5844-456A)) to discover the PD SKUs but the filtering is limited with the methods on the billing API. If I get time, I'm going to write a quick Golang sample because, until I read your question, I was unaware that this API is available and it looks interesting!

One other way to discover the SKUs is using the Billing Reports Explorer:

[image]